# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Which class raised?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have the following code in my controller:

```
def update
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  house = House.find(params[:house_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  # How do I know whether finding user or finding house raised the exception?
end
```

How do I know which `find` raised the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any methods on the error instance to determine *what* raised the error.

You could potentially do this:

```
def update
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  person = Person.find(params[:person_id])
  house = House.find(params[:house_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  case e.message
  when /#{Person.name}/, /#{User.name}/
    do_something
  when /#{House.name}/
    do_another_thing
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could use `find_by_id`:

```
def update
  user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
  person = Person.find(params[:person_id])
  house = House.find_by_id(params[:house_id])

  do_something if user.nil? || person.nil?
  do_something_else if house.nil?
end
```

Comment: Just a question: How could I add an 'OR' in ```/#{Person.name}/```, for example if I have two models that I want to do the same thing

Comment: You can either change the regex to be `/#{Person.name}|#{Thing.name}/`, or you can do `when /#{Person.name}/, /#{Thing.name}/`.  The when statement can take multiple parameters and if it matches any, then that when block gets executes.  I've updated the example.